# Variable extraction to var in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

When extracting a variable (ctrl+alt+v) in Intellij IDEA with Java 11, I would like for the default to be that it is extracted to a `var` instead of the verbose type.

```
var home = "127.0.0.1";
```

instead of

```
String home = "127.0.0.1";
```

Is there a way to configure Intellij IDEA to do this?

Comment: didn't get possibly what you're trying to achieve, deleted the answer. though what is it that you're eyeing, is it changing the variable name or type (suggestions)?

Comment: There is related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190495

Comment: @nullpointer I would like the default *type* to be `var` and not `String`

Comment: Probably the IntelliJ people share my preferences, to produce code as explicit as possible, not forcing a future reader to reason about the variable type.

Comment: This will be more helpful in complex types with generics. Like HasMap<String,List<Some class>>

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff you would think that they would make the IDE as configurable as possible to cater to the preferences of _all_ of their users...

Comment: @y.bedrov I'm not sure that that is the same issue - i'm referring to the default type of the variable upon extraction, not an issue with code compilation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JetBrains added this feature to IntelliJ 2019.1.1.

[image: variable extraction in IntelliJ 2019.1.1]

Comment: how to enable this from settings?

Comment: @VadymOzarynskyi the settings ui was changed i believe it looks like this now https://i.imgur.com/jR2SUrk.png

Answer (score 9):

### Update

Feature has been implemented and available since IntelliJ IDEA **2019.1** release

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179176

*Fix versions   2019.1 (191.6183.87)*

---

This feature hasn't been adopted by IntelliJ IDEA yet.

I've submitted an explicit feature request at JetBrains' bug tracking system: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206367

Although, other similar tickets which have been submitted before, are not yet completed:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179176
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198828

### Alternative

However, you can somewhat achieve the desired behavior by using [Custom Postfix Templates](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9862-custom-postfix-templates) plugin, which allows to define your own custom [postfix completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-postfix-completion.html) templates.

Statement like this:

[image]

Will be converted to:

[image]

To achieve this:

- 1) Install **Custom Postfix Templates** plugin via *Settings → Plugins → Browse Repositories*.
- 2) Press *Shift+Alt+P* (or go to menu *Tools → Custom Postfix Templates → Edit Templates of Current Language*) to open the custom postfix templates for the programming language in your current editor.
- 3) Add the following template:

  ```
  .var : Extracts variable as inferred 'var' type
      NON_VOID                 →  var $VAR:suggestVariableName()$ = $expr$;
  ```

Restart IntelliJ and you're good to go.

**Note**. Existing postfix completion named 'var' exists in IntelliJ by default, you might want to disable the existing one (via *Settings → Editor → General → Postfix Completion*) or find another name for a new one.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206367/Support-Extract-Variable-as-var-Java-10-local-variable-type-inference), it can be enabled as follows from 2023.2 version onwards.
[image: Enable var by default]